# Interactive Report with dynamic sql and binded variables (sql injection)

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-23

I am building an Interactive Report. Source Type is `Function Body returning SQL Query`. And below is my query which is prone to sql injection. How can i bind variables here?

```
declare

vsql varchar2(4000);

begin

    vsql := 'SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE 1 = 1 ';
    --# There are other checks as well for both SELECT and WHERE which are making this query dynamic
    if :P1_NAME is not null then
        vsql := vsql || ' AND UPPER(NAME) LIKE Upper('%''' || :P1_NAME || '%'')';
    end if;

    return vsql;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. The example below has dynamic table and a variable in the where clause using `LIKE`.

The idea is to sanitize the table name (or any other sql objects) using `DBMS_ASSERT.SQL_OBJECT_NAME` and use bind variables where possible. So the generated query will still have bind variable substitution.

The double %% is needed because % is a special character in the apex_string.format function:

```
DECLARE
    l_query varchar2(4000);
    l_table_name varchar2(400);
BEGIN
    l_table_name := DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name(NVL(:P142_TABLE_NAME,'EMP'));
    l_query := 
    q'!select
                      EMPNO,
                      ENAME
                   from
                      %0
                   where 
                      ENAME LIKE '%%'||:P142_EMPLOYEE_NAME||'%%'!';
    l_query := apex_string.format(l_query,l_table_name);
    return(l_query);
END;
```

query in debug:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your query is correct and not prone to sql injection, specially :P142_EMPLOYEE_NAME part?

Comment: Yes, P42_EMPLOYEE_NAME is a bind variable and is sql injection proof. It gets vulnerable when page item values are concatenated, that is not the case here.

Comment: Seems like the query returned is not the final query, it is further parsed by the apex engine and binded varaibles are resolved to make the final query. This is working as well `vsql := q'~ select name from test where NAME LIKE '%' || :P1_NAME || '%' ~';`

Comment: The query in the screenshot *is* the final query. It is a query that has bind variables in it. APEX passes the query and the bind variable values to the oracle sql engine where this query is parsed. I would think APEX does not resolve bind variables.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, there's no need for *dynamic SQL* as there's nothing dynamic in that `select` statement. Region's source could've been just

```
SELECT name
  FROM customers
 WHERE UPPER (name) LIKE UPPER ('%' || DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_literal ( :P1_NAME) || '%');
```

because

- `like` operator (used with wildcards) will make sure that even if you don't enter anything into `P1_NAME` item, query will return all rows from that table
- if there's a value entered into `P1_NAME`, filter will be applied to result
- `dbms_assert.enquote_literal` will enclose value into single quotes and won't allow any *injection* you're concerned about

  - have a look at examples on [Tim Hall's](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2) site

Comment: It is `DYNAMIC`, Columns and their default values will vary, Where clause will vary, even there will be Unions as well, I have posted a simplified version.

Comment: OK; perhaps you should have said so. Anyway, DBMS_ASSERT is what you should be looking at.

Comment: I don't think this package is good enough against sql injection. I am expecting something `parameterized` e.g. dynamic parameterized query, IR accepting something like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_qry USING [Variables];`, Cursor via DBMS_SQL package, etc.

Comment: Context is important here: how is `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` being called in your code? If your code is expecting bind `[variables]`, then the number of variables must be fixed, and you should not be using concatenation to build your query with literals that bypass the use of those bind variables. That's generally what exposes you to SQL injection in the first place. That said, using `enquote_literal` ensures that a string parameter is just that, and cannot be executed independently. Can you provide a use case that demonstrates otherwise?

Comment: @pmdba I am not using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` because it is not supported by `Interactive Report` as I have mentioned in my question. Let me tell you once again that I am building an `Interactive Report` and need to use dynamic query with filters.

Comment: *you* mentioned `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. Context is important. How are your applying this query to your report? Interactive Reports aren't meant to be dynamic in this manner.

Comment: @pmdba There is no `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in my question, it is there in my comments and it was a kind a of wish. A wish to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with `USING`in my Interactive Report. Please read the question and my comment once more to get a clear context.

Comment: @bjan the IR expects a query that you generate. If you assert the table and column names using the available ```DBMS_ASSERT``` subprograms (check the docs) then your query should be rock solid. If you think differently then pls post proof that you're able to SQL inject.

Comment: @KoenLostrie How about sql injection via arguments as i have shown in my question i.e. `UPPER(NAME) LIKE Upper('%''' || :P1_NAME || '%'')`? This is supposed to be a dynamic query so the final query will be there in a string variable. Please refer to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3611/sql-injection-why-isnt-escape-quotes-safe-anymore and similar topics

Comment: Show a working example of sql injection pls using the enquote_literal function littlefoot referenced

Comment: @KoenLostrie Dcoumentation says ` If individual single quotes are found, the "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error" exception is raised.` means it does not allow single quote in user's filter! Do i have to apply some trick here! `enquote_literal` does not seem applicable/good-solution-in-its-own here.